# How do you kill Nabstablook?

Tags: undertale

I am playing Undertale at the moment, and I couldn't help wondering if there is a way you can kill Nabstablook, the ghost that you encounter in the ruins. I've done every single run in the game, including corrupted pacifist, and I still cannot kill him.

Comment: You can't kill him per se. However, you can cheer him up (simply repeadetly use the cheer action during the encounter) and beat him that way. He also fades away if you do the genocide run.

Comment: @CrowleyAstray if you have an answer post it as such - just provide some more detail and where the information came from

Comment: Is the problem that you can't kill him, or that you can't encounter him?

Comment: I can't kill him, whaddya think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible to "kill" Nabstablook in Undertale. You can attack him and lower his HP however when his HP runs out he'll tell you that you weren't actually hurting him because he is a ghost and that he was pretending to lower his HP to make you feel better and phase away after you "defeat him".

Comment: It's worth noting that Napstablook will not appear during a  Genocide Run. The spot where he normally appears will be empty.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro it's not empty if you encounter him before the "But nobody came..."